# how to select button by particular text using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, laravel

I am trying to change CSS of button using jquery, but i am not able to find the button using text property, my JQuery is:

```
 $.ajax({
        url : "{{url('booktable')}}",
        type : "GET",
        data : {},
        success : function(data){
          $.each(data, function(index, element){
            if(element.table_aval == 0)
            {
              var elmt = element.table_no;
              $('#table button[text='+elmt+']').css('color','red');
            }

          });
        }
      });
```

buttons are group of button created by foreach loops, thats why I am trying to find it using text attribute, how can i do that, buttons are:

```
                         <tbody>
                        @foreach($tables as $table)
                        <tr id=""> 
                            <!--input type="hidden" name="table_no" id="tno" value=""-->
                            <td style="text-align: center;">
                              <button class="btn" >{{$table->table_no}} </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                      </tbody>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the color of all buttons ?

Comment: no, i want change color of button whose text is equal to element.table_no

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code will help you: https://jsfiddle.net/auczzk5x/

You fill a text input with word: *special* or *unspecial*. And buttons below have `text` atributte with value of one of these words. For example, if you type *special* and click *Clorize Buttons* than buttons with `text="special"` will be in red color.

In your code above there is no HTML element with `id="table"`, that you use in jQuery code: `$('#table button[text='+elmt+']')`, what suggests that buttons are in element with `id="table"`.