# select a button by its text in Pyppeteer (Python Puppeteer)

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, puppeteer, pyppeteer

I want to click the following button using `pyppeteer`

```
<button class="r3f3s" tabindex="0">Text here</button>
```

I am trying to do it using `Jquery` like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088403/how-to-select-button-by-particular-text-using-jquery):

```
btn = await page.querySelector('button[text=\'Text here\']')
```

or here:

```
btn = await page.querySelector('button:contains(text(), 'Text here'))
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I also noticed that a lot of examples published online in Jquery doesn't seem to work it Google chrome's console, thus doesn't work on `pyppeteer`.

My question is how can I select button by its text, and also, can anyone direct me to a guide explaining what Jquery selector syntax is the right one to work on Google chrome's console (puppeteer)? because [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) doesn't seem correct and this error is not really indicative:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': is not a valid selector.
at <anonymous>:1:10
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS selector *contains text* is not currently supported, but you can use Xpath.

Exact match text

```
btn = await page.Jx('//button[text()="Text here"]')
```

Contains text

```
btn = await page.Jx('//button[contains(text(), "Text he")]')
```

Comment: In Python, `await page.Jx('//button[contains(text(), "Text here")]')`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and solved it by using
`await page.waitForSelector(selector)`

Answer (score -3):

`[]` is the css attribute selector. [Square brackets in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041149/square-brackets-in-css)

`:contians()` is a jQuery selector. https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

The button element doesn't have a `text` attribute. It would be `textContent`. But in practice, it usually doesn't work for me. I also don't recommend `:contains()` as it will return all selectors that contain that text. (ex. 'text here', 'text here now', 'text here then', 'was text here').

When I want to find something by text, I use `.filter()`. http://api.jquery.com/filter/

```
$('button').filter(function() { return this.textContent === 'Text here'; });
```

Not familiar with `pyppeteer` or how this would work with that, but hope it helps.