# Node.js: Text CSS selectors for textContent possible?

Tags: css, node.js, css-selectors, puppeteer

I want to log in to exact profile using puppeteer library, but the order of profiles change every time I try to log in. This means, I cannot access exact CSS selector to choose correct profile, because CSS selector change also with order. After writing `document.querySelector("functional_selector")` in developer console in my browser it shows me this:

```
<div class="login-userinfo-subtitle">
     "name_of_profile"
     "non_changing_information"
</div>
```

I want to see, what "name_of_profile" is (what exactly is in string). "non_changing_information" is something which every profile has in comon.

So, my question is, how can I access "name_of_profile"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/54048044/5430833 it's not possible using CSS/jQuery selectors. But you can do it using XPath, if that's okay for you. Example below:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
 const page = await browser.newPage();
 page.goto('http://example.com');
 await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
 console.log("Done");
 const element = (await page.$x("//h1[contains(text(), 'Example')]"))[0];
 const text = await page.evaluate(e => e.textContent, element);
 console.log(text);
 browser.close()
})()
```

which yields

```
Example Domain
```

in your case it'd be:

```
const element = (await page.$x("//div[contains(text(), 'non_changing_information')]"))[0];
```

If it has to be via CSS selectors, you could filter all `div`s like that:

```
(await page.$$eval('div', a => a
            .filter(a => a.textContent.indexOf('non_changing_information') >= 0)
))[0]
```